# ASIHTTPRequest Crashing on Second Call

Tags: ios, crash, asihttprequest

I have a view controller that has a button that triggers a method to send a request to a web service (using JSON).  The method triggered creates a `ASIFormDataRequest` object and sends the JSON string successfully to the web service.  I know that this is successful because I have put NSLogs in the `requestFinished` method and they are writing out to the console (plus, the web service is processing the data properly).

After this has successfully executed I hit the button again (yes, sending the same data to the web service).  The app crashes.

`[53166:6203] *** -[CFURL release]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x4c5dd00`
`[Switching to process 53166 thread 0x6203]`
`[Switching to process 53166 thread 0x6203]`

XCode then highlights the `CFRunLoop()` function within the `runRequests` method in the `ASIHTTPRequests` class.

I have tried calling `[request cancel];` in the `requestFinished` method, but that doesn't work either.

Comment: Are you recreating your ASIHTTPRequest object for each button tap? If not, should you be?

Comment: I don't believe that I am.  I will redo the code on this one and recreate the ASIHTTPRequest object.  If all goes well I'll close this question out.

Comment: OK.  I modified my view controller.  I have two methods and each calls their own ASIFormDataRequest objects.  Each of them returns a different JSON string the web service.  They are connected to their own buttons.  When I press the first button, it works fine.  When I go to press the other button it crashes the same was as my original question.  Is there some conflict with the persistence that exists with ASIHTTPRequest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to figure this out.  As I'm still new to iOS dev and getting my head around the memory management, the answer is a little light.  But basically, I was releasing an NSURL variable within my methods.  As soon as I commented this out, it works.

As a side note, I also modified my code to leverage an NSOperationQueue as mentioned here: http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use#using_a_queue